# Custom Action Messages

Tags: iphone, ios

UIControl makes a set of "action messages" available on controls that inherit from it. These get exposed as IBActions in UI Builder. Is it possible for me to make my own action messages?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to declare an `IBAction` (return type is void):

```
- (IBAction)clickHere:(id)sender;
```

when editing a nib, interface builder uses the declarations in your class header (as well as those in base classes) to construct the list of actions.

further details can be found in the *Xcode Integration* chapter of *Interface Builder User Guide*.

Comment: Keep in mind that `IBAction` is defined as `void`, so if you declare it as `- (void)clickHere:(id)sender' it would work.

Comment: @Alexsander Akers IB won't add it to the list of actions when it is declared `void` rather than `IBAction`  (unless you and i are using different toolkits, and the behavior has changed).

Comment: For me it does, so long as there is a `sender` argument.